# How can I receive touch events immediately after presenting a scene in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

Using SpriteKit, I have a scene, `XYZMyScene`, that presents another scene, `XYZMyOtherScene`, when I touch on the screen. Without lifting my finger, I want `touchesMoved:withEvent:` to fire as I move my finger around, but it does not fire until I first lift my finger, then touch down on the new scene and move around.

Is it possible to do get it to fire without lifting my finger first?

Here is some simple reproduction code:

```
//  XYZMyScene.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface XYZMyScene : SKScene

@end

//  XYZMyScene.m

#import "XYZMyScene.h"
#import "XYZMyOtherScene.h"

@implementation XYZMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {        
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor orangeColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    XYZMyOtherScene *otherScene = [[XYZMyOtherScene alloc] initWithSize:self.frame.size];
    [self.view presentScene:otherScene];
}

@end

//  XYZMyOtherScene.h

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface XYZMyOtherScene : SKScene

@end

//  XYZMyOtherScene.m

#import "XYZMyOtherScene.h"

@implementation XYZMyOtherScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {        
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"moving!");
}

@end
```

Comment: I would suggest you move the elements of XYZMyScene to XYZMyOtherScene and handle everything from the same scene.

Comment: @akashg - I don't know about that. It sort of sounds like it counters everything I've ever learned about division of labor and OOP. There's got to be a better solution...

Comment: Well, according to what I understand about XYZMyScene, it doesn't really do much.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot carry over a touch from one class to another.

Without knowing your code or your ultimate intentions for this action, the only suggestion I have is for you to set up a class property for your `XYZMyOtherScene` class and have it carry over whatever data you need to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At this time, I don't have data that I want to carry over. Pretty much, I want to have one scene displayed when my finger is off the screen, and then another scene presented when my finger is on the screen. Is there a way to force `XYZMyOtherScene` to start listening for `touchesMoved:withEvent`? If so, maybe I can call that in its `didMoveToView:` method...